# Mongodb sort documents by complex computed value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo, mongoengine

```
items = collection.aggregate([
        {"$match": {}},
        {"$project": {
            'temp_score': {
                "$add": ["$total_score", 100],
            },
            'temp_votes': {
                "$add": ["$total_votes", 20],
            },
            'weight': {
                "$divide": ["$temp_score", "$temp_votes"]
            }

            }
        }
    ])
```

The total_score and total_votes have stored in the document,

I can get temp_score and temp_votes as expected, but can't get weight, any suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `$temp_score` and `$temp_votes` are not existing yet in your `$divide`.

You can do another `$project` :

```
db.user.aggregate([{
    "$project": {
        'temp_score': {
            "$add": ["$total_score", 100],
        },
        'temp_votes': {
            "$add": ["$total_votes", 20],
        }
    }
}, {
    "$project": {
        'temp_score':1,
        'temp_votes':1,
        'weight': {
            "$divide": ["$temp_score", "$temp_votes"]
        }
    }
}])
```

or re-computing `temp_score` and `temp_votes` in `$divide` :

```
db.user.aggregate([{
    "$project": {
        'temp_score': {
            "$add": ["$total_score", 100],
        },
        'temp_votes': {
            "$add": ["$total_votes", 20],
        },
        'weight': {
            "$divide": [
                { "$add": ["$total_score", 100] },
                { "$add": ["$total_votes", 20] }
            ]
        }
    }
}]);
```

You can also do this in one single `$project` using the [`$let` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/) that will be used to create 2 variables `temp_score` and `temp_votes`. But the results will be accessible under a single field (here `total`)  :

```
db.user.aggregate([{
    $project: {
        total: {
            $let: {
                vars: {
                    temp_score: { $add: ["$total_score", 100] },
                    temp_votes: { $add: ["$total_votes", 20] }
                },
                in : {
                    temp_score: "$$temp_score",
                    temp_votes: "$$temp_votes",
                    weight: { $divide: ["$$temp_score", "$$temp_votes"] }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}])
```